# Is there a built in way to know if a scope is a child of another scope?

Tags: angularjs, scope, parent-child

Given two scopes - x, y - is there a **built in** function that returns true if x is an ancestor of y?

(I can obviously traverse from y to the `$rootScope` using `$parent` and compare `$id` along the way)

EDIT:

In the meanwhile I'm using something like this:

```
function isChildScope(parentScope, childScope) {
    while (childScope) {
        if (parentScope.$id === childScope.$id) {
            return true;
        }
        childScope = childScope.$parent;
    }
    return false;
};
```

Comment: May be this could answer this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13428220/1059101

Comment: @Jai - That answer has nothing to do with my question... I'm not trying to access a child scope, just figure out if one scope is an ancestor of another.

Comment: So do you want it in code or angular chrome extension named batarang would surely help you.

Comment: @Jai I switched from batarang to [ng-inpector](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ng-inspector-for-angularj/aadgmnobpdmgmigaicncghmmoeflnamj) I find it not as buggy and  much more detailed.

Comment: In code. And by the way, batarang doesn't support latest versions of angular.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no built-in method on `$scope` in the source, so I doubt it's somewhere else. You probably can compare `$id` as you said or simply `x.$parent === y` to check that.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to clearly identify which `controller` a `$scope` belongs to I would recommend **Controller As**

```
<!-- In Your Binding -->
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl as ctrl">
   <span>{{ctrl.foo}}</span>
</div>

<!-- In Your Controller -->
app.controller('MyCtrl', function() {
     this.foo = "Hello World!";
});
```

This syntax will double bind the `controller` but will make the `$scope` you are working with clearly defined.

---

Here is a nice example with nested controllers that show how readability is improved.

```
<div ng-controller="MainCtrl as main">
  {{ main.title }}
  <div ng-controller="AnotherCtrl as another">
    Scope title: {{ another.title }}
    Parent title: {{ main.title }}
    <div ng-controller="YetAnotherCtrl as yet">
      Scope title: {{ yet.title }}
      Parent title: {{ another.title }}
      Parent parent title: {{ main.title }}
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, but this is not what i'm looking for.

Comment: _if x is an ancestor of y_...is this answers it?

Comment: Sorry @seldary, That is really the best answer I have for this.   The reason I suggest this is because it forces you to set values in the proper scope instead of depending on parent scope.

Comment: No - suppose you are writing a utility aimed for testing relations between scopes (for tests, performance, etc..). Moreover, you might have scopes created by third party plugins, where you don't have access to their templates.

Comment: In no case am I depending on a parent scope.