# Retrieving angular controller via $scope in unit test

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine

I'm trying to retrieve the controller via $scope in my jasmine test, but fail miserably. Anybody know why?

When using the controllerAs syntax, the controller object is put on the $scope object using the name specified in controllerAs. So by running the code below in a browser using ng-app='MyApp' to bootstrap to angular, I can use chrome-dev tools to locate and select the directive element, and type `$0.scope().myDirCtrl` in the console. This does yield the controller object, so why can't I retrieve the controller object in my unit test?

Running the snippet below will kick off a standalone jasmine browser testing environment. The spec for the test is listed at the bottom of the snippet. The code I'm having issues with is this:

```
expect($scope.myDirCtrl).toBeDefined();
```

```js
/* --------------------------------------
    Source code
   --------------------------------------*/
(function(angular) {
  'use strict';

  // Setup the template -----------------
  angular.module('MyApp.tpls', [])
  .run(['$templateCache', function($templateCache) {
    $templateCache.put('partials/myDirective.html',
                       '<div>{{myDirCtrl.testValue}}</div>');
  }]);

  // Setup the app ----------------------
  angular.module('MyApp', ['MyApp.tpls'])
    .directive('myDirective', myDirective)
    .controller('MyDirectiveController', MyDirectiveController);

  function myDirective() {
    return {
      restrict        : 'E',
      templateUrl     : 'partials/myDirective.html',
      transclude      : true,
      controllerAs    : 'myDirCtrl',
      bindToController: true,
      scope           : {},
      controller      : 'MyDirectiveController'
    };
  }

  MyDirectiveController.$inject = ['$scope'];
  function MyDirectiveController($scope) {
    var ctrl = this;
    ctrl.testValue = 'Only a test';
  }
})(angular);



/* --------------------------------------
    Test specifications
   --------------------------------------*/
(function (module) {
  'use strict';
  
  // Define the tests -------------------
  describe('My directive test', function () {
    var $compile, $rootScope, $scope;

    beforeEach(module('MyApp'));
    beforeEach(inject(function(_$compile_, _$rootScope_) {
      $compile   = _$compile_;
      $rootScope = _$rootScope_;
      $scope     = $rootScope.$new();
    }));

    it('scope should contain a controller reference', function () {
      var element = $compile(angular.element('<my-directive></my-directive>'))($scope);
      $scope.$digest();
      expect($scope.myDirCtrl).toBeDefined();
    });
  });
})(module);
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jasmine/2.3.4/jasmine.css">

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jasmine/2.3.4/jasmine.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jasmine/2.3.4/jasmine-html.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jasmine/2.3.4/boot.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.1/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.1/angular-mocks.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `$scope` in your spec is not the same scope that is used in a `MyDirectiveController`. Directive creates one more scope for a controller, which becomes a child of your spec scope. You should be able to check it with the help of Angular internal properties in your test:

```
it('scope should contain a controller reference', function () {
    var element = $compile(angular.element('<my-directive></my-directive>'))($scope);
    $scope.$digest();

    // controller is actually in a child scope
    console.log($scope.$$childHead.myDirCtrl);

    expect($scope.myDirCtrl).toBeDefined();
});
```

But I would not suggest to rely on these private Angular properties like `$$childHead`, because they are considered private and are not the part of public API. I think this Q/A [AngularJS - Access to child scope](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13428042/angularjs-access-to-child-scope) could help you to resolve this issue.

Comment: You are right. `expect(angular.element('> *', element).scope().myDirCtrl).toBeDefined();` yields true. Is this always true for directives, or is it something that's true only for a particular DDO setup? If the latter, what setting constitutes a need for creating a new childscope for housing the controller? `transclue : true`?

Comment: In your directive you have a property `scope: {}`. By defining this extra property you force a directive to create it's own a so called 'isolated' scope. ([docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive#isolating-the-scope-of-a-directive)). If you remove it, it will inherit from a parent scope and test will pass.

Comment: Of course *facepalm*. I knew this actually, just didn't think of it in my unit test... How stupid of me. Thanks so much...