# Using value of lower level divs in ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, ng-show

```
          <div  ng-show="level1.collapsed || level2.selected"  ng-repeat="level1 in main"> ...
                <div ng-if="level1.sub"> 
                    <div ng-show="level2.collapsed" ng-repeat="level2 in level1.sub">
                        ...
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

I have a nested div-structure and as shown in my code i want to change the visibility of div in higher level depend on a value of lower level div.

In my code, `|| level2.selected` does not recognized. Is that possible to do that using a similar way? Preferably without using any variable which should be defined in a controller.

Comment: How do you set level2.selected?

Comment: This question will shed light on your problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13428042/angularjs-access-to-child-scope

Comment: You don't need access to child scope. Write a function `levelHasActiveChildren()` and use in `ng-show="level1.collapsed || levelHasActiveChildren(level1)"

Comment: the problem with `levelHasActiveChildren(level1)` is that i take all the elements in level 1 and not only the relevant ones (thus not like in ng-if in my second line. `levelHasActiveChildren(this)` brings also undefined. I believe it will be better if i can reach them without using js.

Comment: and it is executed several times. Suppose it is defined in 4. level; it is executed #1 * #2 * #4 times

Comment: Are `main` and `main[0].sub` arrays?

Comment: Yes; they are the arrays of my tree

Answer (score 0):

You cannot access child scope from parent scope. You must do it the other way around.

One solution is to bind `level2.selected` to the parent scope by using `level2.$parent.selected` **where you set the property**, not in `|| level2.selected`. This will make it available in the parent scope from the child scope.

Comment: what does it mean to access parent scope where you `set the property`? Setting the property can happen in one scope, for example in controller `main[2].sub[1].selected = true;`. And nested scope in template exist only because of usage of `ng-repeat` directive. There is nothing assigned there

Comment: Can you apply your possible solution to my example? If i am not wrong, your answer is not applicable because i have no any `selected` attribute in my parent in order to change the visibility of him.