# AngularJS hide a nested element when the parent is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have the following markup:

```
<div class="firstView" ng-controller = "watchVideo">
      <figure id = "positionVideo" ng-controller = "MenuCtrl" ng-hide = "!menu" ng-show = "displayVideo">
        <load-video></load-video>
      </figure>
</div>
```

These are the controllers:

```
angular.module('homePage').controller('watchVideo',  ['$scope', '$location', function($scope, $location) {
    $scope.displayVideo = false;

    $scope.videoAvailable = function () {
      $scope.displayVideo = true;
      console.log("videoAvailable");
    };

    $scope.closeVideo = function() {
        $scope.displayVideo = false;
        console.log("closeVideo");
    };

    $scope.playIt = function() {
        if (jQuery("#playVideo").get(0).paused) {
            jQuery("#playVideo").get(0).play();
        }
        else {
            jQuery("#playVideo").get(0).pause();
        }
    }
}])

.controller('MenuCtrl', ['$scope', '$location', '$rootScope',

  function($scope, $location, $rootScope) {
    $scope.menu = false;

    $scope.menuOpen = function() {
        $scope.menu = true;
    }

    jQuery(".firstView").get(0).onclick = function() {
          if ($scope.menu) {
              console.log("window");
              $scope.menu = false;
              jQuery("#playVideo").get(0).pause();
              $scope.$apply();
          }
      };

   }
]);
```

This is the `loadVideo` directive:

```
angular.module('homePage')
  .directive('loadVideo', function($document, $window) {
    return {
      templateUrl: 'partials/video/video.html'
    }
})
```

This is video.html:

```
<video height = "50%" width = "150%"  id = "playVideo" ng-click="playIt(); menuOpen()" poster = "images/eagle.jpg" controls>
          <source src = "images/lion.mp4" type = "video/mp4">
 </video>
```

My problem is the video is being hidden when I click on it, but I want it to hide when the parent div `firstView` is clicked on.

**UPDATE**

The problem was being caused because I was not stopping event propagation on the child. Following is the code that works perfectly.

html:
`menuCtrl` was not required.

```
<div class="firstView" ng-controller = "watchVideo" > 
      <figure class="logo" ng-controller = "logo" ng-click="goToUrl('/home')"> </figure>

      <cite>Every brand has a story.</cite>
      <h2 id = "h2Heading"> <a ng-click = "videoAvailable()">Watch the video </a></h2>
      <aside> &#x2192; </aside>

      <div id = "positionVideo" ng-click = "menuClose()" ng-show = "displayVideo" ng-hide = "!menu">
        <load-video></load-video>
    </div>
</div>
```

video.html:

```
<video ng-click="$event.stopPropagation(); playIt()" height = "75%" width = "75%"  id = "playVideo" poster = "images/eagle.jpg" controls>
          <source src = "images/lion.mp4" type = "video/mp4">
 </video>
```

`menuClose` in `watchVideo` controller:

```
 $scope.menuClose = function() {
          $scope.menu = false;
          console.log($scope.menu);
          jQuery("#playVideo").get(0).pause();
    }
```

**UPDATE 2**

I just noticed that I did not need to initialize the new variable `menu` or create the function `menuClose` either. I reused the function `closeVideo` and variable `displayVideo` to achieve the same functionality. I refactored my code as follows:

```
<div id = "positionVideo" ng-click = "closeVideo()" ng-show = "displayVideo">
        <load-video></load-video>
    </div>
```

`closeVideo` in `watchVideo` controller:

```
$scope.closeVideo = function() {
        $scope.displayVideo = false;
           jQuery("#playVideo").get(0).pause();
    };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add ng-click on your parent div and set the menu variable to hide. No need to add custom javascript in your controller.

```
<div class="firstView" ng-controller = "watchVideo" ng-click="menu=false" ng-init="menu=true" ng-hide = "!menu">
  <figure id = "positionVideo" ng-controller = "MenuCtrl"  ng-show = "displayVideo">
    <load-video></load-video>
  </figure>
```

Comment: I tried the following, but it does not work. `<div class="firstView" ng-controller = "watchVideo" ng-click = "menuClose()">       <figure id = "positionVideo" ng-controller = "MenuCtrl" ng-hide = "!menu" ng-show = "displayVideo">
        <load-video></load-video>
      </figure> </div>` <br> I changed my controller as follows:`$scope.menuClose = function() {
          $scope.menu = false; }`

Comment: I think the problem is that you use the menu which is defined in child controller in the parent controller. you can change controller places and whenever you need to access your parent variables you simply need to access that by parent.YourVariable

Comment: You can use this answer if it helps: (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13428042#answer-28374175)

Comment: I added the `menuClose` function in the `watchVideo` controller not the `menuCtrl`

Comment: does the child `div` disappears?  Cuz I forgot to mention that you should add `ng-hide = "!menu"` to the `<div class="firstView" ng-controller = "watchVideo">`

Comment: Also `ng-init="menu=true"`

Comment: I figured it out. Thanks. Now the problem I am having is when I click on the `div` the video closes, but when I click on the video instead of it pausing or playing (depending on its current state), it closes because it is part of the parent div.

Comment: I updated the answer (still using simpler method with no JS). please do look at it..It has some more explaination..please to mark it correct with upvote..Thanks :)

Comment: That was very helpful, but it still does not solve my question. Unless I do not click on the play button the video is not playing. It is hiding the video because the `video` element is the child of the `div` which is being clicked on. Is there a way to exclude the child element from the parent when using ng-click?

Comment: Ok I think here you should play with variables. In your child div you can add `ng-click="childClick()"` and set the menu to true while you can set a flag to true. and In your parent you can make menu=false with the condition of the flag to be false. i'm working on some JSFiddle for the answer.

Comment: This JSFiddle is similar to what you want, I hope it helps you (http://jsfiddle.net/DrStein/bxw7rg0q/)